# How to put two different images in a single div. Can anyone help me

Tags: html, css, image

I want to put two images in one div. One remains up and other goes down. Both take around 25% width:-

```
<div class="images">
    <div class="pics">
        <img src="GRProvider/Img.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="pics">
        <img src="GRProvider/Img_2.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.images {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
.pics {
    float: left;
    width: 12%;
    margin: 0%;
}
images_img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Make a drawing of what you want / currently have

Answer (score 3):

Try this out using `display:inline-block`

**CSS**

```
.images {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 25%;
 }

.pics img{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;       
 }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/35/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the pics side by side? You only need one line of css:

```
.pics { display:block; float:left; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ve9ud2o4/1/

Or if you want the image container div to be 25% and the pictures to span the div you could do:

```
.images { background:red; display:block; float:left; overflow:hidden; width:25%; }
.pics { background:green; display:block; float:left; width:50%; }
.pics img { border:1px dotted black; display:block; width:100%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ve9ud2o4/2/

Remember that .pics width is relative to it's container. So even though the .images div is 25%, if you want a pic to be half of that you set the .pics width to 50%

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display:block;` to prevent line breaks and display elements in same line 
Of course you can ajust your div width to fit the two images and float them as you wish